# How to add message header in trx framework ISO 8583 , please help me?

Tags: frameworks, trx

I am new in trx framework, How to add message header in trx framework ISO 8583 , please help me ?? any body help me ?

Comment: Masadi have you used connected socket or on demand connection?

Answer (score 0):

I learn form Mr Salamun Fajri (Salcad) to add header message in trx framework just one step.
looks my single line code :

```
 message.Header = new StringMessageHeader("ISO015000017");
```

its very simple, ..